# Getting IOException with NetworkStream.BeginRead()

Tags: c#, ioexception, networkstream, beginread

When running this code:

```cs
private async void StartChat(Object obj)
{
    TcpClient me = (TcpClient)obj;
    UpdateChatBox("Attempting read from server.");
    myBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while (true)
    {
        var myStream = me.GetStream();
        myStream.BeginRead(myBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(UpdateChatBoxAsync), myStream);

        if (messageToSend)
        {
            await myStream.WriteAsync(myMessage, 0, myMessage.Length);
        }                
    }
}
```

I am receiving the following IO Exception from `BeginRead`:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.

Here is the callback method for BeginRead:

```cs
private void UpdateChatBoxAsync(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var stream = result.AsyncState as NetworkStream;
    int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(result);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        String newMessage = NetworkUtils.GetString(myBuffer);
        UpdateChatBox(newMessage);
    }
}
```

Can someone please shed some light as to the reason this exception is being raised? I tried recreating the buffer each time at the start of the while loop, but while that worked in not raising the exception, I would not receive messages from the server.

I also attempted to reset myBuffer to an empty array at the end of UpdateChatBoxAsync, this did not work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a low-level Windows error, WSAENOBUFS.  Pretty unusual to get that on a BeginRead call.  Could be [kernel memory pool exhaustion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a44b064-8872-4edf-aac7-36b2a17f662a.aspx), could be that you have way too many sockets opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running an infinite loop without any throttling. You are issuing async read calls as fast as the CPU can do it. This creates unlimited amounts of outstanding operations.

You are supposed to issue the next read when the last one has completed (most commonly done from the callback).

By just adding

```
if (myStream.DataAvailable)
```

you avoid the read but still burn one CPU core. This is just a mitigation for one of the symptoms. Fix the root cause instead.

It seems you should not be doing async IO at all because you don't have a problem with blocking. You're blocking a thread and burning 100% of a core. If that was acceptable, don't even bother with async IO.

Or, use `await ReadAsync`.

Comment: So what do you think a correct solution would look like? Why would using await ReadAsync fix this problem? Just looking for some clarity. Thanks!!

Comment: `await ReadAsync` only continues processing after the current read is done. That's key.

Comment: It does not use any threads. It uses async IO. This does not matter for you, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution.

Before trying the `BeginRead` I check to see if the stream has any data available using `NetworkStream.DataAvailable` or in my case `myStream.DataAvailable`

So the new working block of code looks like

```cs
if (myStream.DataAvailable){
    myStream.BeginRead(myBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(UpdateChatBoxAsync), myStream);
}
```

Comment: Check your CPU utilization, probably burning 100% on one core since it's an infinite loop with no blocking.